# Taylor polynomial for 1/(1-x) around 0 only in -1 < x < 1, but why?

Tags: polynomials, taylor-expansion, approximation

I am working on a project, where I make the 4. degree Taylorpolynomaial for the function
$$g = \frac{1}{1-x}$$
Which is:

$$P_4(x)=1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4$$
I understand that to make a Taylorpolynomial, the function we are approximating needs to be differentiable in an interval $I$ where $x_0 \in I$. And that the domain of $g$ is
$$\mathbb{R}\setminus \{ 1 \}$$

$I$ cannot contain $x=1$ since $g$ isn't differentiable here, therefore our approximation of $g$ becomes very bad, since our requirements for the Taylorpolynomial don't hold here and afterwards.

My question then is, why doesn't our approximation hold before $x=-1$

Comment: Because the radius of convergence is $1$.

Comment: You can make a Taylor polynomial centred at, say, $-2$.  That is $3$ away from the singularity, so its radius of convergence is $3$, and it works between $-5$ and $1$.

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what i was looking for. I am attempting to stress how important it is to choose the proper center of developement when approximating.

Comment: The approximation, good or bad, holds, it is just that it does not become better when you increase the degree. The polynomial exists, but the series does not converge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because, in this case, we have the exact value for the remainder in Taylor's formula:

From a well-known high-school factorisation formula, we have
$$\frac1{1-x}=1+x+x^2+\dots+x^n+\frac{x^{n+1}}{1-x},$$
so that the remainder $\:\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{1-x}\:$ tends to $0$ as $\:n\to \infty\:$ *if & only if* $\:|x|<1$.